# Setting REST value to $scope.value on POST is NULL but accepts hard value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple form that posts to my REST backend. I have a total of 2 fields on the form, but three values I want to populate.

Using the following form, I have users enter in the articletitle and articlesummary

```
<div ng-controller="pfcPost">
<form ng-submit="createTask()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newTask.articletitle"
           placeholder="add new task here">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newTask.articlesummary"
           placeholder="add summary">
    <input type="submit" value="create">
</form>
</div>
```

However, I also want to set a value in my DB for the articlelink to be the articletitle (later, I will adapt this to be the title without spaces, etc.).

Here is my controller:

```
    pfcControllers.controller('pfcPost', ['$scope', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, pfcArticles) {

    $scope.newTask = new pfcArticles(
        {
        articletitle: $scope.articletitle,
        articlesummary: $scope.articlesummary,
        articlelink: $scope.articletitle
        });
    $scope.createTask = function () {
        // call the service
        $scope.newTask.$save(function () {
            // when saved, reload the list and recreate a new task
        });
    }
}]);
```

Currently, it does not post the value of $scope.articletitle to articlelink, but shows it as null

However, if I change it to a hard value, such as follows, it works.

```
        $scope.newTask = new pfcArticles(
        {
        articletitle: $scope.articletitle,
        articlesummary: $scope.articlesummary,
        articlelink: "hard value"
        });
```

Here is the backend factory:

```
    var pfcServices = angular.module('pfcServices', ['ngResource'])

pfcServices.factory('pfcArticles', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://myrestcall.net/articles/:articleID', { articleID: '@id' },
    {
        'update': { method:'PATCH'}
    }
    );
}]);
```

Any clues why it is not taking the scope item as the value? The other values populate without issue.

Comment: implementation og pfcArticles?

Comment: I don't see $scope.articletitle or $scope.articlesummary defined anywhere. I'm surprised they are getting values at all with the code that is posted here.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the factory. I believe that since the controller is tied to the form, $scope is being passed. If this is not correct, please guide.

Comment: I have also tried it this way, but it doesn't save anything unless its hard coded. Scope issue?:     pfcControllers.controller('pfcPost', ['$scope', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, pfcArticles) {

       

        var artentry = new pfcArticles;
            
                artentry.articletitle = $scope.articletitle;
                artentry.articlesummary = $scope.articlesummary;
            
        $scope.createTask = function () {
            // call the service
            artentry.$save();
        }
    }]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working via the following:

Inputs:

```
<div ng-controller="pfcPost">
<form ng-submit="createTask()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="articletitle"
           placeholder="add new task here">
    <input type="text" ng-model="articlesummary"
           placeholder="add summary">
    <input type="submit" value="create">
</form>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
    pfcControllers.controller('pfcPost', ['$scope', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, pfcArticles) {

    var articleentry = new pfcArticles;

    $scope.createTask = function () {

        articleentry.articletitle = $scope.articletitle;
        articleentry.articlesummary = $scope.articlesummary;
        articleentry.articlelink = $scope.articletitle;

        articleentry.$save();
    }
}]);
```